# analysis of critical success factor of lean implementation to identify the influenced dimention

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Clustering vs EFA which is a good tool for structural equation modeling to identify the influenced variables also to support the hypothesis?

Comment: I think you are going to have to edit this to give us some more detail about what you mean by clustering here and why you want to do either of them prior to fitting a SEM.